# Full Weekly Backup & Daily Incremental Backup

Tags: centos, backup

I have Linux Centos 6.5, and I have tried different backup scripts, but I have failed each time. I only have a small amount of experience with Linux, I've only used it to set up a server etc. so I don't know how to do proper backups. I have a 100GB FTP server connected to my Linux server that I can use for backups.

I need a script that takes a weekly backup and also a daily incremental backup. I only need to backup certain directories, e.g. /home, /etc and so on. It should also automatically execute every week/day and take a backup and put that backup on the FTP server.

Is there anyone who has a proper and working script for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed Centos, you obviously have `crond` tool. Put your routines into the cron, and it will execute any script at the specified time:

```
su #login as root
crontab -e
```

This will run the FTP upload every day at *hh:mm*:

```
mm hh * * * curl --upload-file testfile.zip ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.com/
```

But i find it more useful to use direct filesystem access for creating backups (you need to configure ssh public key access before):

```
mm hh * * day_of_week_number rsync -avh -e --updates --delete /source remote.host:/dest
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding below intro to the crontab will help to take weekly backup of Linux partitions.

```
mm hh * * dow rsync -avh -e --updates --delete /source /destination
```